# Image capture, Save file...Android/Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am attempting to save an image file captured from the mobile to Parse, within an Android app.  I am using  final File mediaFile.  I think my problem is, I know I need to convert the file to a byte array...I've tried various ways to do this.  I can see the image in a preview...but I can't seem to save it to Parse.

Thanks for any help.

```
 public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));

    }


    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        String appName = CameraActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                appName);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(appName, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + appName + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        final File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }




            final ParseFile photoFile;

            FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;


            byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) mediaFile.length()];

            try {
                //convert file into array of bytes
                byte[] data2;

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
                FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
                int sz = (int)fc.size();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sz);
                data2 = new byte[bb.remaining()];
                bb.get(data2);
                // Save the image to Parse
                photoFile = new ParseFile("profile_photo.jpg", data2);
                photoFile.saveInBackground();
                mCurrentUser.getCurrentUser();
                mCurrentUser.put("ProfilePhoto", photoFile);
                mCurrentUser.saveInBackground();

                System.out.println("Done");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return mediaFile;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have try this and its work for me...!

```
currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
//here bitmap is your selected photo's bitmap    
bitmapProfilePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("Profile.png", image);
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            currentUser.put("ProfilePhoto", file);
            currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                     @Override
                     public void done(ParseException e) {
                          if (e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Updated..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Picture Updated..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error to " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

in your case you have already byte data in data2 so,...

```
final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("YourPhotoName.jpg", data2);
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            currentUser.put("ProfilePhoto", file);
            currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                     @Override
                     public void done(ParseException e) {
                          if (e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Updated..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Picture Updated..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error to " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks...so in my code, the mediaFile variable goes where bitmapProfilePic is in your code?  In my code, it is created here:  mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

Comment: No in my code bitmapProfilePic  is bitmap of selected image. so you have to convert it into bitmap for use this code.But you have byte[] data so you will able to use it directly.

Comment: Ah, so I have byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) mediaFile.length()];..so I would put:  bFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);?

Comment: No no, you have already byte data in data2, so you have to need just put in parse.I have edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try compressing into the JPEG format, as JPEG compression results in lower sized images than PNG for photographic images.

Try this code:

```
bitmapProfilePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```